# Hide/Show Button On VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionsupport, inputcheckboxes

I am trying to show/hide a submit button on my VF page based on a checkbox but its not rendering.

Here's what I have already tried:

On the controller I have defined the boolean condition as shown below:

```
public Boolean visibleSubmit { get; set; }
```

Then I have added this script below to my VisualForce Page:

```
function termsAccepted() {
        if (document.getElementById('tncs').checked) {
            visibleSubmit = true;
        } else {
            alert("You did not accept the terms and conditions.");
            visibleSubmit = false;
        }
    }
```

Then on the checkbox and button I have set it as follows:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="tncs" required="true" onclick="termsAccepted()" value="{!partnerAgreement}"/>Terms and Conditions</p>

<apex:commandButton styleClass="btn" value="Submit" id="recordSubmit" rendered="{!visibleSubmit}" action="{!insertRecord}"/>
```

Many thanks for the assistance...

Comment: You've got 2 variables for JS and Apex called `visibleSubmit` correct? You're not passing the value of the JS `visibleSubmit` to the Apex one?

Comment: Hi @Poet thank you very much for your response. Yes I have named the variables **visibleSubmit** should I give them different names. My apologies I am not quite following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a variable's value in javascript won't update it in your APEX controller and also won't rerender the commandbutton.

You have 2 options:

1. go javascript. Arrange the button visibility by css  styling
2. go visualforce. Arrange the button visibility by visualforce

I'll give an example of the Visualforce way here, as we're on the salesforce boards :-)

When the checkbox is checked, you want to do 2 things: update the `visibleSubmit` boolean and rerender the `commandbutton` so it will be shown (or not).

In order to do that, the first step is to associate the visibleSubmit variable directly with your checkbox:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="tncs" required="true" value="{!visibleSubmit}"/>
```

(Not sure what the `partnerAgreement` variable is that is currently in the checkbox? If that's a boolean as well, you might use that instead of visibleSubmit to decide whether or not to render the button. But then you also have to use 'partnerAgreement' in the 'rendered' option of the commandButton.)

Secondly, you need to rerender the commandbutton when the checkbox changes. The way to do that is using an [actionsupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm). The actionsupport can be directly attached to the checkbox. Also you need to wrap the commandButton in a panel, so that you can easily rerender the panel:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="tncs" required="true" value="{!visibleSubmit}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="theButtonPanel" />
</apex:inputCheckbox
<apex:outputPanel id="theButtonPanel>
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn" value="Submit" id="recordSubmit" rendered="{!visibleSubmit}" action="{!insertRecord}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Guy -- Minor point ... I think you meant use `actionSupport`, not `actionFunction` as that is what your example shows.  Goal is to invoke an AJAX event so controller is called and a partial page refresh can be done. `actionSupport` will transmit values to setters but not invoke an action method in the controller; `actionFunction` will invoke an action method and can pass parameter values to setters. Either would work for the OP but your solution is simplest

Comment: Thank you very for the assistance and explanation. You were very helpful

Comment: Thanks guys but currently I am getting the error below: **apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.**   I tried to wrap the commandButton inside  <apex:actionregion></apex:actionregion> but I am still getting the error.

Comment: an apex:inputfile on the page changes matters quite a bit.. In order not to mix up questions and answers, I'd suggest opening a new question and including your vf page (including the inputfile). Then refer it here, so I can find it and help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this is my first answer!!!

I have just done this in my org using `<apex:actionSupport/>`

This is a very simple code:

VF Page:

```
    <apex:page controller="DisplayButtononCheckboxEvent">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputpanel id="counter">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="button">
           <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!check}"/>  

           </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:outputpanel>
        <apex:outputPanel id="button">
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" rendered="{!check}"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class DisplayButtononCheckboxEvent {
    public boolean check{get;set;}
}
```

Do let me know if this helps you..
Happy Coding!!!

Comment: thanks a lot Rishab but I am getting the following error:                                          **apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.**

Comment: Hey there, the error you are getting is for **apex:inputFile**, which is a little different. To help you out I need the Code of VF page, you can share the code by posting a new question and can share the link in comments. Hopefully we can solve the issue.

Comment: thanks Rishab will do that, how can I chat with you, if possible

Comment: Hey User23, Sorry for the delay in comment. You can chat with me on skype : @rishabhseth123 or can get in touch with me on gmail rseth.sfdc@gmail.com